# How to determine the number of active linearly independent constraints in a basic feasible solution for linear programming?

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, matrices, polygons

I am trying to determine if a given solution is a basic feasible solution. I am working with an $n-$dimension polyhedron $P$ defined by a set of $M$ inequalities $Ax \leq B$. I am running into an issue where I am not sure how to determine if a solution is basic feasible or degenerate. Working off of the following definitions, from [harvard.edu/lecture_notes](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/%7Eyaron/AM221/lecture_notes/AM221_lecture7.pdf):

- A solution in $P = {x : Ax \leq B}$ is called **basic feasible** if it has $n$ linearly independent active constraints.
- A solution in $P = {x : Ax \leq B}$ is called **degenerate** if it it has *more than* $n$ linearly independent active constraints.

If you were to define a new matrix $A'$ that consists of only the active constraints, how do you find the number of linearly independent constraints within $A'$? In the case of a pyramid, the pinnacle of the pyramid is a basic feasible solution that is represented with four constraints, of which three are independent. So, in this example, $A'$ would consist of four constraints, of which, we would want to be able to find that three of the four constraints are linearly independent.

Is there an efficient way to calculate the number of linearly independent constraints from a set of active constraints?

Comment: You can do Gauss elimination (using column transformations) to put the system of equations (the active constraints) in echelon form. Any active constraint that becomes $0=0$ is dependent on the other active constraints. If I remember correctly the Simplex algorithm updates the system in such a way that it keeps the active constraints already in echelon form. If I am not remembering correctly then one way to do step (3) in Algorithm 1 in your notes is to do Gauss elimination.

Comment: @plop is it sufficient to calculate the rank A' using Gaussian elimination to determine if a system is basic feasible or degenerate? I'm not sure if I am oversimplifying this problem.